# Duvida com Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

Estou utilizando Dialog para exibir uma certa informação no meu APP, gostaria de saber se tem alguma função para eu verificar se o dialog já está aberto para não abrir novamente.

```
 public void Dialogo_Iluminacao() {


    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogo_iluminacao);

    dialog.setTitle("Iluminação");

    final Switch garagem = (Switch) dialog.findViewById(R.id.switchGaragem);


    garagem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {


    });


    dialog.show();
}
```

Tenho uma função que sempre que chega algo nela deve mostrar esse dialog e muitas vezes chega varias e gostaria que o dialog inicializasse somente uma vez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode verificar através do método `isShowing()` (não esqueça de verificar se ele está nulo, apenas por precaução):

```
if (mDialog != null  && mDialog.isShowing()){
    //suas implementações
}
```

Referência: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#isShowing()

Comment: Não consegui implementar poderia sitar um exemplo ??

Comment: O que você quer dizer como não conseguiu implementar? Deu erro, deu crash, não foi chamado o método...? Poste algum trecho de código

Comment: como utilizo essa função? coloco ela dentro do meu método Dialogo_Iluminacao ?

Comment: Antes de mostrar o seu `Dialog`! Você mesmo disse que "Tenho uma função que sempre que chega algo nela deve mostrar esse dialog e muitas vezes chega varias". Nesse momento, você faz essa verificação

Answer (score 0):

Só chamar o método:

```
 dialog.isShowing()
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html